# Two different VSDB Projects for DBCreation and Population?

Tags: sql, vsdb

I've just stated developing with vsdb, and while it seems to be functional, it seems like it introduces unnecessary restrictions.

Effectively what I'd *LIKE* to do is use it to manage database creation, as well as upgrades etc. In creating, nothing special, just a if db not exists create db, and add a couple logins.

I'd like to push out the changes to tables/views/sprocs/funcs etc... but it seems like it wants me to make this two projects... which is fine... but seems like unnecessary complexity.

I guess my question is to be able to point this .dbschema at a server and have it create database if needed as well as populate the database with schema and data.

Is this really going to require of me 2 projects for each database I want to automate the deployment of?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more detail on why you ran into needing 2 projects?

I'm managing a "2 database" deployment and use 4 projects, but not for the same reasons.

1. Server project - for Logins
2. A stub project for DB-A because some of it's items are referenced by DB-B.
3. DB-B's project
4. DB-A's project

If I only had one of the databases without the cross-database links, and didn't need to manage server-level items also in the project, it would only require one project.